# Notepad++ Search Window disappeared

Tags: notepad++

I'm working with NotePad++ text editor, the 'Search Results' window does not show up anymore, i've tried to open it from the menu (Search Result Window F7), but it does not seem to have any effect, how can i restore it?

Comment: I know this is an old question. I wish they always open the "find window" (not intending the search 'results' window) on the same screen as the npp main window.
Right now, the monitor preferences for the 2 windows (main and find) are tracked separately by the OS.

Comment: in my case , deleted the config.xml of notepad++ and restarted the notepad++ . 

If you installed the notepad++ via installer it would be under %APPDATA%/notepad++ or if you are using binary then it is in parent folder .

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The issue seems happens if I change monitors configuration , e.g. if I worked on laptop with 2 attached monitors, and next time open Notepad++ when having single laptop monitor.

For me it was sufficient to delete %appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml (not the whole folder).

1. Close Notepad++
2. Open %appdata%\Notepad++ folder (e.g. C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Notepad++ )
3. Delete (or rename in case if you want a backup) config.xml
4. Start Notepad++

Comment: For people who are wondering where this %appdata% is located. Here is an example: C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData

Comment: Deleting works, however you can also just change the X and Y property (to 0) of FloatingWindow:
            <FloatingWindow cont="4" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" />
(this way you don't lose other settings)

Comment: I closed NPPP, renamed "config.xml" as "config.xml.BAD", relaunched NPPP, which did retrieve the NPPP Search Results, BUT ALSO, as expected, lost a (large) PART OF my other settings. However this did NOT create as expected a new "config.xml", so I can't restore my (numerous, after decades of use) missing preferences and other settings.

Comment: %appdata% c:\users\xxx\Appdata\Roaming\Notepad++ for Notepad 8.3 on Windows server 2016

Answer (score 41):

This works for me without deleting the `%appdata%/Notepad++` that deletes the highlight themes.

1. search any pattern: this is so the FOCUS will be on that invisible search-result window.
2. then hit `Alt + Space, M`
3. move around your mouse until the search-result window show up.
4. position the window to your desired position.
5. hit `Enter`.

**Edit:**

If moving the mouse did not work, press `Alt + Space, M` and then press any arrow button and then move the mouse. The window should appear and now following your mouse.

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Moving my mouse didnt work but the left and right keys brought it back into view.

Comment: If I try this, I get into the "Mark" tab of the search dialog box.
I could disable this via Settings>Shortcut Mapper

Comment: Worked for me. Need to make sure the search will have some result and of course do a "Find in files", not a regular search.

Comment: I tried many of the possible ways to interpret your advice, I do get the 'Move' cursor (a fine straight cross), but it always applies to the main window of NPPP (Notepad++).

Comment: All variants of your advice failed. Most lead to focus on the main NPPP window, or on the Search DIALOG, NOT the Search RESULTS. Your advice could be more efficient if you detail what you mean: while holding down the "Alt" key, type "Space" then "M", then release the "Alt" key? Or so many variants...

Comment: These instructions are for the **FIND DIALOG and not for the Search Results Window** (which is very helpful if that's what your looking for). For Search Results Window please try one of the other responses.

The full instructions spelled out:
1. Hold Down: Ctrl
2. Press: F
3. Relase: Ctrl
4. Hold Down: Alt
5. Press: Spacebar
6. Release: Alt
7. Press: M   (If your locale is not English, you may wanna try with just pressing Enter instead)
8. Press: Left Arrow
9. Move mouse cursor to where you want the search window to be positioned
10. Left mouse click

Answer (score 16):

Although deleting `%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml` works you also loose many other settings.

After some experimenting I found that if I simply delete the following line

`<PluginDlg pluginName="dummy" id="0" curr="4" prev="3" isVisible="yes" />`

in the `%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml` file then the "Find result" window goes back to being docked on the bottom half of the Notepad++ window.

Comment: Worked for me, seems a much better option than deleting the whole file. The find result window appeared centered after deleting the line and closing/re-opening Notepad++.

Comment: I've deleted  4 <PluginDlg > entries, but no success

Answer (score 9):

Edit file

```
%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml
```

Fix negative values of *x* and *width* attributes in the FloatingWindow tag. In my case it looks like that:

```
<FloatingWindow cont="4" x="-1692" y="252" width="-40" height="910" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, when open the Notepad++, the window appears and immediately becomes hidden.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim It seems like it is a different issue in your case. In my case the error appeared after connecting/disconnecting additional monitors.

Comment: yeah, it seems mine was using the size and position over the second screen I sometimes use. I just reset x and y and that was it

Answer (score 8):

It appears the 'Search Results' window is located outside the screen, the easiest way to get it back is to wipe out notepad++ settings, 
you can remove %appdata%\Notepad++ folder, start again notepad++, it should appear now

Answer (score 8):

The window had moved to extreme bottom of the NotePad++ screen. I just had to drag it up.

Answer (score 8):

You may try Turn on View > **Always on top**
The Find result may just hide under the Windows taskbar.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you for SOS.

Comment: the best answer ever. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The find window is actually there but has a height of zero.  Hover over the top of the status line and you find a window border.  Drag it up and your find window will appear!

Answer (score 3):

Out of all the answers here, nobody mentioned the one that worked for me, so I thought I'd add it to the pile:

My problem was the following line in `%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml`:

> <GUIConfig name="DockingManager" leftWidth="200" rightWidth="200" topHeight="200" bottomHeight="0">

The item `bottomHeight="0"` was effectively hiding the docked window. I just changed this to 100, and it reappeared.

Like @Sebas in the comments, this might have been caused by enabling and disabling a second screen.

Comment: Upvoting TonyK's answer because it gets to the specific problem.

After making that change you may wish to try <ctrl F> then search for all instances of the string in that file, to see if the search box pops up (it doesn't show until a search is run)

Answer (score 2):

For me, Press F7.

You can see all the Shortcut map by going to Settings -> Shortcut Mapper. From there you can scroll down to "Search Results Window". Mine is set to F7.

Comment: Dunno why someone downvoted this. It is the same for me, all I have to do is hit F7 now to restore.

Answer (score 2):

1.Open the Find Dialog.

2.Set Find what to something you know exists in the current docuemnt.

3.Run Find all in current document
.if Find Results Window shows up as either a window or a panel, your problem is
solved. Otherwise, continue

4.Exit Notepad++ completely

5.Use Explorer to go to %AppData%\Notepad++ , and for config.xml, Open With Microsoft’s Notepad (the default windows “Notepad” app, not Notepad++)

6.Copy the following two groups of lines, and paste into your reply:

1.The “AppPosition”:
`<GUIConfig name="AppPosition" x="1834" y="39" width="1419" height="700" isMaximized="no" />`

2. The complete “Docking Manager” section:

```
<GUIConfig name="DockingManager" leftWidth="200" rightWidth="200" topHeight="200" bottomHeight="200">
<FloatingWindow cont="4" x="2519" y="308" width="2860" height="446" />
<PluginDlg pluginName="Notepad++::InternalFunction" id="44085" curr="0" prev="-1" isVisible="yes" />
<PluginDlg pluginName="Notepad++::InternalFunction" id="0" curr="4" prev="3" isVisible="yes" /> 
<ActiveTabs cont="0" activeTab="0" />
<ActiveTabs cont="1" activeTab="-1" />
<ActiveTabs cont="2" activeTab="-1" />
<ActiveTabs cont="3" activeTab="-1" />
<ActiveTabs cont="4" activeTab="0" />
</GUIConfig>
```

It may have a lot more lines than that. But I need everything between `<GUIConfig name="DockingManager"` and `</GUIConfig>` in order to help you find your Search Results window.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how serious is the change in the settings. Sometimes it's just hidden because you pushed it down to the taskbar. So go to the end and when the cursor becomes size image drag the Search Results window.

In some cases that the window was dragged out and closed. You need to get rid of custom setting. Try to wipe out

%appdata%\Notepad++

The last resort:
Re install it and don't forget to confirm removing your custom settings. 
First uninstall
Then fresh install

Answer (score 1):

It may just be minimised at the bottom of the Notepad++ app. Hover your mouse cursor over the top of the bottom status bar of the application and drag up.

Comment: This answer is the same as that from @Jahmic that was posted almost two years ago. Answering questions here is good but please do not duplicate existing answers. New answers to old questions should provide new information or give new insights into the proble,.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

For me in:

```
%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml
```

I changed:

```
<FindHistory transparency="200"
```

to:

```
<FindHistory transparency="100"
```

And it showed back up.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally checked the radio button "Always" inside the transparency option inside the Find window which made it go permanently transparent. What I did is just minimised all the windows on desktop and opened notepad++ window and then clicked the restore button next to close button to make the notepad++ window smaller and then I could see the find window with permanent transparency beside the window and clicked the "on losing focus" option in transparency again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the setting I had to update:

Setting internal function ID 0 to curr="3" prev="-1" and isVisible="yes" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply switching notepad++ to fullscreen discovered the undocked results dragged below the bottm of the screen by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line from config.xml and reopen notepad++.

```
<GUIConfig name="FindWindowPosition" left="454" top="708" right="1043" bottom="1072" />
```

On portable version is on the same directory you have notepad++ main program.
On normal installation config.xml is on %appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml

Answer (score 0):

I tried it all and nothing worked. What worked was deleting or rather renaming the config.xml file (this one: `%appdata%\Notepad++\config.xml`).

If you miss any settings or search history from the renamed config.xml file, you can just copy them into the new config.xml file (make sure you close Notepad++ first so the new config.xml file is created).

By the way all open tabs remained open when I did it (the open tabs were not affected by config.xml).

Answer (score 0):

1. ctrl + F => Find dialog opens
2. searchString => "Find All In Current Document" this will bring the Find result pane to be the “active window”, if its in the background
3. Alt+SPACEBAR => this should bring up the Find Result window, if you had closed the search window previously, it will be collapsed at the bottom of the screen - near "Normal text file" - you can drag from the mouse and expand.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a old thread but we may closed the window for any reaason. To view it again,

Search -> Search results window or simply F7 to view the search window.

Answer (score 0):

Programmers Notepad, which I believe is partially based on Notepad++, has the same issue: the Replace (search and replace) window will disappear, typically after changing screens/monitors, which I do a lot in different remote work setups. In some cases, it ends up with zero height, for which the keyboard methods on this discussion thread won't work. But they are close.

For both editors, if you make the window active (i.e. it has Window's "focus"), then press Alt + space, then select Size, the Windows "cross style" cursor appears, which will be in the center of the zero height window (I know, there is no such thing as center of 0,0). Then you can move the mouse around a bit until you see the cursor change to the "diagonal sizing style", at which point you can click and hold and move the mouse to expand the window so the window becomes visible.

Jahmic's and TonyK's answers should be max upvoted as they (i) point to the root issue (zero height window, due to some calculation going on by the editor when screen sizes change in mid-operation) and (ii) hint at how to solve the problem without restarting the editor or deleting config files.

Answer (score -1):

Open a text file with regular notepad. Closed it. Open the same file with notepad++, search window is back.